# Accessing Xamarin.Forms inside ViewModel

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I am very new to Cross platform development in Xamarin.forms. My code should be highly unit testable and I have created a `ViewModel` class to communicate between my `View` and the `Model`. I want to know, If we are going to access Xamarin.forms (using Xamarin.Forms;), inside the viewmodel, is it a bad practice or violating MVVM concept. If so How we can use Command inside ViewModel to bind with the view.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Accessing the view from the view model is indeed "against" the MVVM principle. So, you're right on that! Binding a `Command` though, isn't that hard and works just as any other binding that you might've used.

In your view model, just define a property for the `Command`:

```
public class YourViewModel
{
    public Command YourCommand { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the constructor define the logic that should be executed:

```
public YourViewModel()
{
    YourCommand = new Command(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TADA!");
    });
}
```

Of course, you could define it is it's own separate method or declare it another way. For brevity, I have done it inline for now.

To bind to it from XAML, simply do:

```
<Button Text="Make it so!" Command="{Binding YourCommand}" />
```

and make sure that you have set the `BindingContext` property on your page to the view model. If you are using an MVVM framework you might have already done so.

At some point, you will probably want to bind to a cell in a `ListView` or similar. In that case, keep in mind that the scope changes. You are then binding to the view model behind that cell and not the page. So, you will have to make a reference to the page to reach that `BindingContext`. But cross that bridge when you get there, just keep in mind that there is something special about it.

Comment: Inorder to acces Command we need to import Xamarin.Forms into our ViewModel. I want to know is this illegal? Because I have heard we should not import Xamarin.Forms into our ViewModel

Comment: Ah that is what you mean. You could go for `ICommand` if it is really bothering you. But referencing Xamarin.Forms isn't that bad. As long as you don't reference your view from the view model.

Comment: If I tried to use ICommand like this,  ConvertToGeoCodeCommand = new ICommand(ConvertToGeoCode); "Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or Interface 'ICommand'"

Comment: ICommand is an interface, you can't create an interface directly. But you could define it as an interface, so it would be: `public ICommand YourCommand { get; set; }` but then, if you really don't want a reference to Xamarin.Forms you will need some kind of factory pattern because else when you do `YourCommand = new Command(...)` you still need the reference. If I were you I would go for the regular command for now and when you start to get the hang of it and you still want to get rid of the reference, look at ways to do it then, when you have learned the basics.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code, so you don't need to import Xamarin.Forms in your ViewModel:

**ButtonBehavior**

```
 public class ButtonBehavior : Behavior<Button>
    {
        protected override void OnAttachedTo(Button bindable)
        {
            base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
            bindable.Clicked += Bindable_Clicked;
        }

        private void Bindable_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Use you logic here
        }

        protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Button bindable)
        {
            base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
            bindable.Clicked -= Bindable_Clicked;
        }
    }
```

**View**

```
    <Button Text="Click Me" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="80">
        <Button.Behaviors>
            <behavior:ButtonBehavior/>
        </Button.Behaviors>
    </Button>
```